# How to open a logfile in windbg from a script, such that each logfile is named by the timestamp of creation?

Tags: debugging, logging, windbg

I want to run a windbg script that will accomplish the following:

I want to track certain registers the moment an API is hit, without stopping due to timing issues. So , the moment the API is called, I want the script to open a logfile, echo the fact that the api is hit with the details of the parameters, and let it run till it hits the conditional brkpoint I've put at the API end, which simply closes the open logfile.

Now , the problem is, I want to do this multiple times, w/o the previous logfile getting overwritten. Ideally, if there is some command which lets me specify that the name of the logfile (`.logfile file`) by the timestamp of that moment, my problem is solved.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy:
I'll have to use `.logopen /t filename` - what a no-brainer :)